# Angular 4 Observable interval with forkjoin?

Tags: angular, http, observable, subscribe

I have a recurring function that sends 2 API calls every 3 seconds.  I want to change this to run every 3 seconds AFTER the previous call was completed. So only if I get a success or error response does the function run again.   How can I adjust this function?

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.subscription = Observable.interval(3000).subscribe(() => {    
   //http get request
   //http get request 2
  })
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by I get a success or error response does the function run again? Can you explain what is the exact expected behavior?

Comment: I have a slow backend so my HTTP get request are usually still pending before the next one gets sent. I want to make sure I get an 200 OK before the next function runs again.